# how to bind 3 arrays simultaniously using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I tried using ng-repeat value,group1,group2

i'm getting

grp1

grp2

abc

def

value1

value2

I need

grp1

```
  abc

     valu1
```

grp2

```
      def

          valu1  

Html:
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="heading in group1"> {{heading}} </li> // heading
<li ng-repeat="subheading in group2"> {{subheading }} </li> // sub heading
<li ng-repeat="val in value"> {{val}} </li> // value
</ul>



JavaScript:

                             $scope.group1 = [grp1,grp2];
                             $scope.group2 = [abc,def];
                             $scope.value = [value1,value2];
```

Comment: suggest you map your data into nested arrays that fit your tree structure in desired markup. Will find it a lot easier to manage. Should provide more real world examples of data. What is shown is far too primitive to be of much assistance with mapping. Start with models that make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $index to get other sub values

```
 <div ng-repeat="eachval in group1">
   <p>{{ eachval }}</p>
   <p style="margin-left:15px">{{ group2[$index]}}</p>
   <p style="margin-left:25px">{{ value[$index]}}</p>
 </div>
```

Here is the [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/Zj5LG/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single array with three different keys

```
$scope.arrayList = [{group1Name : 'grp1',group2Name: 'abc', valueName: 'val1'},
{group1Name : 'grp2',group2Name: 'def', valueName: 'val2'}]
```

htlm would look like this

```
<li ng-repeat="group in arrayList">
    <div>{{group.group1Name}}</div>
    <div>{{group.group2Name}}</div>
    <div>{{group.valueName}}</div>
</li>
```

You can write a simple javascript to modify your 3 arrays in 1 array.
Hope this helps

Comment: This is not help full for me. my data will be in arrays only and group1Name,group2Name,valueName these are heavy data, when more values will be

Comment: I was thinking of an organised approach, but if so is the case use $index as mentioned above by folks above. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat start and end points to iterate the first array, then use `$index` to reference the other elements:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="heading in group1">{{heading}}</li> // heading
    <li> {{group2[$index]}} </li> // sub heading
    <li ng-repeat-end> {{val[$index]}} </li> // value
</ul>
```